# Can I sign an Android app using Apache Cordova (local build)

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

Have looked around and I cannot see a clear answer to this question. I can see that the Phonegap Build service can assist with signing and Android APK file for submission into Google Play Store.

I am using Apache cordova locally with CLI to build, test and run my Android/iOS apps. My question is, how do I sign the APK file using Cordova CLI, not PGB? My app is too big for PGB.

Would I have to move the project into Eclipse IDE and do it there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not sign an app with Cordova CLI.  Cordova CLI has limited support for platform specific operations, and Android app signing is definitely one of those.

To sign the app (full instructions here: http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html):

- Create a keystore (only need to do this once)
- cd [appname]/platforms/android/
- edit ant.properties and add these values

  - key.store=[location of keystore]/android-release-key.keystore
  - key.alias=[name of your key]
- Remove `android:debuggable="true"` from the AndroidManifest.xml before you run 'ant release'
- run ant release and enter the passwords as needed

At the end, you should have a signed app ready for upload to Google Play.

Comment: Just about all the steps you have noted make sense to me after doing some heavy Android documentation reading. One thing that still eludes me is step 1 - creating a keystore. I thought building iOS apps was a bit difficult!

All I have managed to do is come out with this reference:
"$ keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore
-alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000"

From http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html. I can't figure this out without being an Oracle programmer - WTF?

Comment: Well, I managed to get a keystore using the docs (don't really know what I am doing though). Problem is, I cannnot find the ant.properies file, can only find local.properties and project.properies files. When I go to run "ant build" it comes back with an error saying it cannot find the build.xml file. Does that mean anything? I am pretty sure I have ant installed as it was pretty much a requirement to build android apps with Cordova, Node.js and CLI.

Comment: Lightbulb moment. I did not realise I had to navigate with CLI (Terminal) into the Android project directory - duh!

Comment: Glad this all came together for you!

Comment: My article will help you get the keystore file: https://iphonedevlog.wordpress.com/2014/10/29/signing-an-android-apk-apart-from-eclipse-in-mac-os-x/

Answer (score 0):

with eclipse you can sign you apk very easily.

Just right click on project and got to Android Tools-> Export Signed Application Package-> click Next-> Select Create new keystore-> browse location and enter passowrd for keystore -> click Next->fill all information and finish the process.

Now you have a signed apk which you can install on any android device.

Hope this helps..

Thanks

Comment: I'd love to be able to do it in Eclipse bug somehow I have'goofed' it up as I have used ANT to build Android, therefore its put the SDK in some weird invisible user directory, I'm not even going to pretend I know what is going on there....I keep getting an error message telling me to update SDK in Eclipse which I can never do as it seems I am running two versions of the SDK on my MAC.